# Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Tags: php, mysql

My PHP functions script was working fine last night, and now when I logged on to work on it some more today, I am getting

"Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given".

I have -no- idea why this isn't working. I've read the PHP manual online, and I've even seen examples where what I did is used and works. Can anyone please help me out with this? I've been fixing bug after bug (so many things stopped working when I logged on today) and I'm at my wits end here. If it helps, I'm using XAMPP on Windows 7 for my server.

#### Code: [(also available via Pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/wMDDt3hd)

```
<?php

function dbConnect() {
$dbserver="127.0.0.1";
$dbuser="Mike";
$dbpassword="mike";
$dbname="devsite";

$con = mysql_connect($dbserver, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
}

function getSiteTitle() {


$siteTitle = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT \`siteTitle\` FROM siteSettings"), 0);
return $siteTitle;
}

function getSiteHeader(){

$siteHeader = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT \`siteHeader\` FROM siteSettings"), 0);
return $siteHeader;
}

function getBodyContent() {


$bodyContent = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT \`bodyContent\` FROM siteSettings"), 0);
return $bodyContent;
}

?>
```

Comment: add some basic debugging, check the query works, if not return the error from mysql

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that `mysql_query()` is returning a boolean instead of a result resource. There are two reasons this can happen:

1. You performed query that returns success/fail instead of a result set (e.g. `UPDATE`)
2. Your query failed

In your case the query failed. The reason it failed is because you have escaped the back ticks in the PHP string where you did not need to.

Your lines look like this:

```
$siteTitle = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT \`siteTitle\` FROM siteSettings"), 0);
```

When they should simply be this:

```
$siteTitle = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `siteTitle` FROM siteSettings"), 0);
```

Now, some side notes:

- Don't write new code that uses the `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated and will eventually be removed from PHP. Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead (I personally recommend PDO, YMMV)
- Nesting database functions in this way is not a particularly good way to write your code. It is much better to check the errors explicitly after every function call.

For example:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT somecol FROM sometable");
if (!$result) {
  // Handle error here
}
// Now process the result
```

- You should quote either all identifiers, or none, in your queries (preferably all). Quoting only some makes it harder to read.

E.g.

```
SELECT `siteTitle` FROM `siteSettings`
```

Comment: And to prevent similar future headaches, the OP should check the result of each `mysql_query` issued for success or failure before trying to use the result.

Comment: Indeed, I am just adding a few point including that one at the moment... :-D

Comment: +1 on PDO.  Doesn't bind you to a vendor, and the SQL injection protection is nice.

Comment: I forgot to remove the single quotes from my SQL queries. They failed even without them. I am going to follow your suggestions and use PDO instead. I appreciate all your help... I've never had a formal class of any sort on PHP so I'm really just learning as I go.